# Substring and CharIndex in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in my SQL Server query.

I have a record

```
01Lorem:02Ipsum:003Lorem
```

and another record

```
02Ipsum:01Lorem:03Ipsum
```

I need to get a substring from each record to be `01-02-003` and `02-01-03`

Comment: You reference "my query" but you have not provided it. Please post your query along with the results and/or error messages.

Comment: Does it have to be [`SUBSTRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)? Why not [`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) and/or [`TRANSLATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql)?

Comment: are the strings to be removed are only `Ipsum` and `Lorem`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a complete detailed answer available, but since since the OP appears unresponsive, it is not worth the effort to post it.

Answer (score 0):

this will work only when static string `Lorem` or `Ipsum`

```
DECLARE @Q1 NVARCHAR(mAX) = '(01Lorem:02Ipsum:003Lorem)';

SET @Q1 =SUBSTRING(@Q1, CHARINDEX('(',@Q1) +1 , CHARINDEX(')',@Q1) -2);
SET @Q1 =REPLACE(@Q1, 'Lorem','');
SET @Q1 =REPLACE(@Q1, 'Ipsum','');

PRINT @Q1;
```

**OUTPUT:**

`01:02:003`